# Simple linq question: using linq to get an array of properties

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Lets say we have a simple class

```
public class Foo
{
    public string FooName;
}
```

Now we want to do some simple work on it.

```
public void SomeCallerMethod(List<Foo> listOfFoos)
{
    string[] fooNames = listOfFoo. // What to do here?
}
```

If I even knew what method to call, I could probably find the rest of the peices.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want to transform a list of your class into an array of strings.  The ideal method for this is `Select`, which operates on each element on the enumerable and builds a new enumerable based on the type you return.

You need to put a lambda expression into the select method that returns the name, which will simply be "for each element, select the name".

You then need to cast the output as an array.

```
string[] fooNames = listOfFoos.Select(foo => foo.FooName).ToArray();
```

Or, using the other syntax:

```
string[] fooNames = (from foo in listOfFoos
                     select foo.FooName).ToArray();
```